# How does Google Cloud Datastore run locally?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, nosql

While experimenting with Node.js and Google Cloud Datastore (for the backend of my application), I noticed that even without the Datastore Emulator, I was able to run and test my application locally using Datastore API.

**Note**: I did NOT deploy my app to the cloud.

More specifically, I saw this when I cloned the "nodes-getting-started" github repository, created a config.json file, ran npm install and finally ran npm start. I could add and delete books using the API. Where is this data being stored?

I found this quite interesting and did not know how it works. I would deeply appreciate any help with this. It is eating my brains out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where is this data being stored?

In the cloud, just as if you were accessing it from the cloud. Just because *your application* isn't in the cloud doesn't mean that you can't access services in the cloud.

Try running your application without an internet connection and it will fail. On the other hand, if you look at the [Datastore console](https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/entities/query) you should be able to see the data that your app was working with. (Whereas if you had run your app against the emulator, the data wouldn't be visible in the console, as it would only be present locally.)